# Pods failed to start after switch cni plugin from flannel to calico and then flannel

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel, calico

I install kubernetes v1.11.5 from kubeadm with cni plugin flannel and everything is ok. But I after try to switch to calico I found that the cross machine pod communication is broken. So I switch back to flannel. But got error message when creating pod:

[image]

It seems that I need to reset cni network? But I don't know how to solve this problem.

My flannel and calico installation is follow [kubeadm instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) with zero config update.

Comment: It looks like a conflict between 2 different plugins. A lot of things could possibly went wromng. I guess the simplest solution in such case: setup new CNI from the scratch

Comment: You need to wipe out the cni.  Calico and flannel are using different cidr.  How to wipe out, https://www.cnblogs.com/jiuchongxiao/p/8942080.html. The content is in chinese. I tried the commands and it was ok for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use following steps to remove old calico configs from kubernetes without `kubeadm reset`:

1. clear ip route: `ip route flush proto bird`
2. remove all calico links in all nodes `ip link list | grep cali | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-15 | xargs -I {} ip link delete {}`
3. remove ipip module `modprobe -r ipip`
4. remove calico configs `rm /etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist && rm /etc/cni/net.d/calico-kubeconfig`
5. restart kubelet `service kubelet restart`

After those steps all the running pods won't be connect, then I have to delete all the pods, then all the pods works. This has litter influence if you are using `replicaset`.

Comment: you are my life saver