# Cleaning up installed cni-pluggins

Tags: kubernetes, cni

I am bit stuck with a problem I have.

I am struggling to set up the `cni-plugin` for k8. I was trying to install different `cni-plugins` that now I think many things are messed up.

Is there a way to neatly delete everything connected with a `cni-plugin` so that I can have a clean starting point? The goal is to avoid formatting my whole machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900779/pods-failed-to-start-after-switch-cni-plugin-from-flannel-to-calico-and-then-fla).

​
steps to remove old calico configs from kubernetes without kubeadm reset:

1. clear ip route: `ip route flush proto bird`
2. remove all calico links in all nodes `ip link list | grep cali | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-15 | xargs -I {} ip link delete {}`
3. remove ipip module `modprobe -r ipip`
4. remove calico configs `rm /etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist && rm /etc/cni/net.d/calico-kubeconfig`
5. restart kubelet `service kubelet restart`

After those steps all the running pods won't be connect, then I have to delete all the pods, then all the pods works. This has litter influence if you are using replicaset

Or else you can use:

​
`kubeadm reset` command. this will un-configure the kubernetes cluster.

​

​